# Wordpress Custom Post Type - Show all children categories of current post

Tags: wordpress, categories, children

I have a custom post type of 'products' and in single-products.php I want to show all child categories of the current posts' primary category (used for navigation)

How would I do this? Have tried a few options and nothing works thus far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us some of the options you tried.

Answer (score 0):

First you will get the category of the post using: `$cat = get_the_category($post->ID);`

Then you will get the children of that category using: `$cat_children = get_term_children( $cat, 'category' );`

Then you will loop through the children like so:

```
foreach($cat_children as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by('id', $child, 'category');

    // Display children here
}
```

Here are links to each of the functions referenced here:

[get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

[get_term_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)

[get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

**EDIT:** You can swap out the `category` term in each of these functions to target custom taxonomies.